# What is the difference of using generic BLoC provider and Inherited widget?

Tags: flutter, difference, concept

What is the difference of using generic BLoC provider and Inherited widget? Are they the same, do the same, or are they completely different?

I understand that both serve to access a data regardless of the level you are in the widget tree
But I would be very pleased if you explained the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They serve a similar purpose (deliver state to widgets further down the widget tree), but there are differences in how to retrieve values and how to apply changes.

In BLoC, you build widgets depending on the current BlocState by using `BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyBlocState>` and you `add` events to the `BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context)` in order to change that value.

With InheritedWidgets, you can get the current state by `context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MyInheritedWidget)`. But `InheritedWidget`s are immutable (fields are marked `final`). You can only change the state, by rebuilding the entire widget. Thats why `InheritedWidget` is mostly used for things, that rarely change: `Theme`, `MediaQuery`, `Localization`, etc.

Comment: i want to get it more , Assuming we have bloc that contains child widget 
and Inherit widget that contain its child widget 
When data update occurred, what's happening?

u mean that inhert widget child will rebuild it all 
but bloc widget will only rebuild child if the updated data in its child like Text(updatedData)
or what ???